# How to integrate TestStand User Interface during deployment?

Tags: teststand

I made some test sequences and a workspace in TestStand. I want to deploy those sequences and make a MSI based executable. However, I am not sure how can I include the files for Simple or Full Featured UI into the workspace and include it during deployment or call the UI content folder directly during the deployment.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just insert folder with custom user interface into workspace https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/teststand/page/tsref/infotopics/db_add_file_to_wksp.htm.

Then you will see inserted files in Deployment Utility.

But better practice would be to separate installers of user interface, and sequence itself. Because mostly you will do more changes/updates/fixes to sequence files, so you will need to redeploy just them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big undertaking, but may be worth it for you depending on the size of your company.  TestStand has an [API](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/documentation/supplemental/08/teststand-user-interface-development-best-practices.html) that you can use to develop a custom GUI.  That GUI can then open any sequence file you like after being compiled as a C program that runs as an executable file.